# ArrowKt Try alternative for eager execution

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming, arrow-kt

ArrowKt has deprecated [Try](https://arrow-kt.io/docs/apidocs/arrow-core-data/arrow.core/-try/) since it promotes eager execution of effects and it recommends to use suspend constructors. 
But how should I handle following case where I do want eager execution on purpose without using traditional [try-catch](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/exceptions.html).

```
 fun getMainAccount(accounts: List<String>): Either<Exception, String> {  
   return Try {
     accounts.single()
   }.toEither().mapLeft {
     InvalidAccountError()
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need for any special construct beside `try/catch` in Kotlin, since it's also already an expression. For that reason it was removed from Arrow, you can simply write:

```
fun getMainAccount(accounts: List<String>): Either<Exception, String> =  
   try {
     Right(accounts.single())
   } catch(e: Exception) {
     Left(InvalidAccountError())
   }
```

Or you can also easily write a utility function for it yourself.

```
fun <A> Try(f: () -> A, fe: ): Either<Exception, A> = 
   try {
     Right(f())
   } catch(e: Exception) {
      Left(e)
   }

fun getMainAccount(accounts: List<String>): Either<Exception, String> =
   Try { accounts.single() }.mapLeft { InvalidAccountError() }
```

Answer (score 5):

There is now an easier way

```
fun getMainAccount(accounts: List<String>): Either<Exception, String> = 
    Either.catch {accounts.single()}
```